# If statement does not repeat when condition is met?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I want the script to keep prompting the user for a valid input which is from 0 to 100 but can't get it to work. I am more confused than when I started to work on this script last night. This is my homework and the teacher has asked us to use if statement that is why I haven't tried to use the while loop but maybe I should.

Here is the code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Grade</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var grade = Number(prompt("What did you score: ", "Your Score Here!"));

    if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {
      grade = Number(prompt("Please enter a valid score", "Your Score Here!"));
    } else if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60) {
      grade = "F";
    } else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70) {
      grade = "D";
    } else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80) {
      grade = "C";
    } else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90) {
      grade = "B";
    } else if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
      grade = "A";
    }

    document.write("<strong>Your grade is:</strong> " + grade);
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you'll need a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you would use a `while` loop. In this case you would have a flag that checks if the input is invalid. We can assume it's valid in the loop, and when the invalid check goes through change it to being invalid (false), and cause the loop to repeat.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Grade</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var grade = Number(prompt("What did you scrore: ", "Your Score Here!"));
    var valid = false;
    while(!valid)
    {   
        valid = true; // assume it's valid
        if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {
          grade = Number(prompt("Please enter a valid score", "Your Score Here!"));
          valid = false; // It it happens to not be valid, change it to invalid
        } else if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60) {
          grade = "F";
        } else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70) {
          grade = "D";
        } else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80) {
          grade = "C";
        } else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90) {
          grade = "B";
        } else if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
          grade = "A";
        }
    }
    document.write("<strong>Your grade is:</strong> " + grade);
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow you answered my question within 6 minutes, that is mind blowing I would aspire to be as good as you one day. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @SomeDude Adding a while loop isn't a big deal. Once you get used to them it's quite simple :P But thanks :) *Note:* You can accept answers by clicking the green check on the left.

Comment: I tried to vote your answer up but its telling me that I need to have at least 15 reputation points, I think because I am new that is why and I can't see anything greet in the whole page. Note: I found it, the check is gray until you click it, than it becomes green :P.